# Why do the researchers usually study the collection of **nonempty** closed subsets?

Tags: general-topology, hausdorff-distance

In the research field of hypertopologies, researchers usually study on **nonempty** closed subsets of a topological space, although I have seen, but a very few books or articles, where the authors have studied the collection of closed subsets **including the empty subset**. I am curious, why do the researchers usually study the collection of **nonempty** closed subsets? Is there any particular purpose behind it? What I think is: while the application of hypertopologies in optimization, nonlinear analysis, well-posed problems, etc. authors don't face the empty set; however, I have not gone thoroughly through the application part of hypertopologies, what I think is my guess.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular field  but it is likely due to various theorems that would have to exclude the empty set if you kept it in, while leaving it in doesn't get you anything.  Kind of like why we decided 1 wasn't a prime number

Comment: Why would you want to study the empty set in any context?

Comment: In most hyperspace topologies, the empty set appears as an isolated disjoint point (consider, at least, the upper and lower Vietoris topologies). Since it tends to add annoying quantifiers to many statements and break up their final symmetry (say, regarding connectivity), without adding any real mathematical content, the empty set is usually excluded at an early stage.